# How to see all action items from all documents in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?hl=en shows how to see "the follow-ups on a document"

[image]

How do I see a list of all action items assigned to me, by myself or others, from within the desktop Google Drive interface, for all documents I have visibility of, without having to know ahead of time and click upon each specific document those Action Items stem from?

It is not apparent from the available documentation if these things are exclusively called "comments" or "action items", or both, so I'm assuming they are action items.

Ideally, this would be a feature built-into Google Drive if possible.  But if there is a free app that provides this, then that would suffice.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a detailed and clear question specifically about functionality in the Google Drive Desktop App which is off-topic ([help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 0):

You can view all your action items via https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=followup:actionitems&usp_dm=true

but this won't include others AIs.

Comment: This question is about the "desktop Google Drive interface" not the web app (see paragraph 1)